# Complex database search

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have an sql query which searches the database to find stores within 20 mile radius of a postcode however I cant seem to get the keyword search to work.

```
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['keywords']));

$sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($userLat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) )
* cos( radians( lng ) - radians($userLng) ) + sin( radians($userLat ) )
* sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM firms
HAVING distance < 20
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
AND WHERE keywords
LIKE %$search%";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
```

Comment: What happens with this code? `mysqli_real_escape_string(`  requires a connection string. You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you i removed the `mysqli_real_escape_string(`  and it wokrds

Comment: That's not what I meant. You are even more open to SQL injections without that. If you are going to use that approach you need to use it correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columns
     , I
     , actually
     , want
     , ... as distance
  FROM firms
 WHERE keywords LIKE :search
HAVING distance < 20 -- or AND ... < 20
 ORDER 
    BY distance 
 LIMIT 0 , 20
```

and use parameterized queries

Comment: You need to escape the `"` or use single quotes, since it's inside a double-quoted string.

Comment: You can't have `OR WHERE`, it should just be `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

RTM: [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) You're not calling it properly.

And even if you were, your query has syntax errors:

```
LIKE %$search%";
     ^--------^---missing quotes
```

So you're generating the literal SQL

```
SELECT ... LIKE %foo%
```

instead of the

```
SELECT ... LIKE '%foo%'
```

you should be

Comment: But why would anyone be using _real_escape_string anyway?!?